# Topology on the space of functions

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, algebraic-topology, metric-spaces

[Exercise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gsUx.jpg)

Question ii)

I don’t manage to prove that the intersection of open sets is still open.

Let’s assume that $U_1,U_2,...,U_m$ are in T.
Let $f_0$ be in the intersection of $U_1,U_2, ...,U_m$.
For all i in {1,...,m}, $f_0$ is in $U_i$.

We need to find a global $\epsilon$ and global $x_1,...,x_n$ for the particular set to be still in the intersection of $U_1,U_2, ...,U_m$, while we have such $\epsilon_i$ and $x_1i,...,x_ni$ only for each $U_i$...

One can maybe take $\epsilon$ = max($\epsilon_i$) but to find $x_1,...,x_n$ I really don’t know as they are not the same depending on i.

I don’t see neither how to prove Question iii).

Thank you very much

Comment: You are given a basis of a topology. Can you describe all the open sets ?

Comment: Do you know about the initial topology? Also in the future, please latex your questions

Comment: All the open sets seem to be sets of functions which has a finite difference ε>0 at chosen points x1,...,xn (in fact a unique x in [0,1] should be sufficient, right?) But the functions are defined in [0,1] thus I would have expected no infinite values, so I’m confused

Comment: Sorry for the Latex

Comment: Hint for (iii): the resulting topology is not first countable, you cannot even write $\{f\}$ as a countable intersection of open subsets, as you could if it were metric.

Comment: Ok I will look at this thank you so much!

Comment: Take the union of the finite sets you get for each $U_i$ and the minimum of the $\varepsilon_i$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to prove that the intersection of two open sets is open. Let $f_0 \in U \cap V$. You want to find $\epsilon > 0, x_1, ... x_n \in [0,1]$ satisfying the condition for $f_0$.

You know that $f_0 \in U$ and $f_0 \in V$. Therefore, there exists $\epsilon_1 > 0 , x_{11}, ... x_{1m} \in [0,1]$ satisfying the condition for $f_0 \in U$, and a (possibly different) $\epsilon_2 > 0 , x_{21}, ... x_{2m} \in [0,1]$ satisfying the condition for $f_0 \in V$.

How can you combine them to get a collection that verifies $f_0 \in U \cap V$?

Hint: take $\epsilon < min(\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2)$ and the set $\{x_{11}, ... x_{1m}, x_{21}, ... x_{2m} \}$.